# Can't acces global variable with 'this' with nested function

Tags: javascript, typescript, geolocation, this, ionic4

This is likely a beginners question, but I'm having trouble using 'this' for global variables.
I am using Ionic 4. And I'm trying to post a location to my database.

I have declared the following global variable in my class:

```
export class HomePage {

  myVar:any;
```

I can use it in a function like this:

```
  mainFunction(coordinates) {
    this.myVar = coordinates.coords.latitude;
```

The problem is that when i go one function deeper. The variable can not be accessed with 'this.'.

```
  mainFunction(coordinates) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.helperFunction);
    console.log(this.myVar);

 helperFunction(coordinates) {
   this.myVar = coordinates.coords.latitude;
```

For some reason a nested function can not read or write the global variable. I get the following error:

`ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'myVar' of null`

How do I pass the value of myVar back to mainFunction?
Thanks in advance.

I am calling the mainFunction with a button in a .html

```
 <ion-button expand="block" (click)="mainFunction()"></ion-button>
```

Comment: How are you calling mainFunction?

Comment: I am calling the mainFunction with a button: 

<ion-button expand="block" (click)="mainFunction()"></ion-button>

Comment: @evolutionxbox the problem is with `helperFunction` not `mainFunction`. Since the code is passing the direct reference to it, the context gets lost when invoked.

Comment: The way the geolocation API works is that it passes the coordinates to helperFunction. How can I pass the variable from that helperFunction to my mainFunction?

Comment: The helper function will be called *sometime later*. You cannot directly return anything to the main function. You could make a promise and await it. Or you just do the work that needs doing when the location becomes available inside the helper function.

Comment: Thanks. I solved it this by using `this.helperFunction.bind(this)` .